# How do I overlay the window with an image on top of all the views?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am trying to place an overlay on top of my Activity. In other words, I would like to put a gradient on top of the whole screen with all views behind it.

I currently have a `LinearLayout` with my buttons and everything in it. Do I extend the `LinearLayout` and add something on the `onDraw` method, or is there any way I can add another layout that overlays everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things:

1. replace the LinearLayout with a RelativeLayout and so you can easily place anything you want on top of each other
2. wrap your LinearLayout in a FrameLayout. The FrameLayout draws everything in order of definition/adding so your gradient should be the last added view/layout.

Something like that:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <Your stuff>
    </LinearLayout>
    <GradientView/>
</FrameLayout>
```